# Android Bluetooth File Transfer .apk

Tags: android, file, bluetooth, apk

**Intend:**
I´m trying to develop a single-purpose app, which you can not exit. It should run on a phone as an "operating system". This phone will be used for further purposes. The app will not be in the play store and also you can´t leave it so I need to update it otherwise if I have newer versions. For this purpose I´ve written another app which you could call the "updater-app". I want to do this update via Bluetooth. I already prepared everything and it´s ready for file transfer. The phones can connect by an InsecureRfcommSocket. I also managed to select the .apk file which I want to send with a chooser on the updater-app and I´m converting the uri into bytes in this Code:

```
sendUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mBtService != null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

                try {
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose .apk"), FILE_SELECT_CODE);
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No File-Explorer found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

and the onActivityResult:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == FILE_SELECT_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri selectedFile = data.getData();
        try {
            byte[] sendingByte = readBytes(selectedFile);
            mBtService.send(sendingByte);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.transmissionFailed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

the readBytes function:

```
    public byte[] readBytes(Uri uri) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    int len = 0;
    while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
}
```

with the `mBtService.send(sendingByte)` row the following function is called in the ConnectedThread:

```
        public void send(byte[] selectedFile) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(selectedFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Problem:**
In the receiver phone I´ve got no idea how to receive the bytes and convert it back to a file/uri (no idea yet) .apk and save it to my phone to execute it with another button which is not part of this question.

**Question:**
So my question is what to to in the code of the receiver phone app to manage finish my intend? If I missed to post any relevant code I´m sorry and will add it on your Request. As I have to program this both apps for my studies I´m thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Solution to save the received Bytes to a ByteArray and then save it to a File. In my Bluetooth ConnectedThread I have the following run() method:

```
public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            while ((len = mmInStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
                mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_READ, len, -1, byteBuffer.toByteArray())
                        .sendToTarget();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            connectionLost();
        }
    }
```

And in my Activity I have the following Handler MESSAGE_READ:

```
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case Constants.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                ...
                break;
            case Constants.MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] buffer = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                try {
                    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/app.apk";
                    File file = new File(filePath);
                    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                    if (file.exists()) {
                        file.delete();
                        file.createNewFile();
                    }
                    else
                        file.createNewFile();
                    BufferedOutputStream objectOut = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
                    objectOut.write(buffer);
                    objectOut.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                break;
        }
    }
};
```

With this Code the .apk is saved to the regular Download folder as "app.apk".

Hope this is helpful for anyone.